# QuickBooks API Create Customer POST request FAIL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, post, request, quickbooks-online

I would like to create a customer by quickbooks API.

First thing **everything is working well with a GET request.**

But when I try a **POST** request I get

**Error code="100">General Authentication Error**

Here's the Oauth2 token =>

```
at = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(::QB_OAUTH2_CONSUMER, acces_token)
```

Here's the new_customer =>

```
new_customer =

  {

   "BillAddr": {

     "Line1": "10 rue Des Champs",

     "City": "Paris",

     "Country": "FRANCE",

     "CountrySubDivisionCode": "FR",

     "PostalCode": "75020"

   },

   "Notes": "Just a test",

   "Title": "Mr",

   "GivenName": "John",

   "MiddleName": "",

   "FamilyName": "Doe",

   "Suffix": "",

   "FullyQualifiedName": "John Doe",

   "CompanyName": "DonwtownLA",

   "DisplayName": "DonwtownLA",

   "PrimaryPhone": {

     "FreeFormNumber": "0123456789"

   },

   "PrimaryEmailAddr": {

     "Address": "johndoe@gmail.com"

   }

  }
```

Here's the URL =>

```
at.post("https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/#{realm_id}/customer")
```

Anyone can help me for this I cant see what I'm doing wrong.

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the call using Postman. The following blog post should be helpful.
https://developer.intuit.com/hub/blog/2017/08/03/quick-start-quickbooks-online-rest-api-oauth-2-0

Please check if you are passing the content-type as 'application/json'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
Why I need to use Postman for this ?
And I pass data like this =>
at.post(url, data)

Thanks

Comment: I try with Postman I got the exactly same error =>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2018-01-16T09:08:19.997-08:00">
    <Fault type="AuthenticationFault">
        <Error code="100">
            <Message>General Authentication Error</Message>
            <Detail>AuthenticationErrorGeneral: Internal Server Error , statusCode: 500</Detail>
        </Error>
    </Fault>
</IntuitResponse>

Comment: Postman is a standard tool for API testing. That's why suggested to use it. 
I see that you have raised a support ticket. Please share the screenshot of the postman screen.

Comment: Hello Thanks for your reply !
Here's the 2 screenshot from postman, one succesfull with a GET Request and the other with the error on POST request.

http://res.cloudinary.com/dgq8rxb4v/image/upload/v1516182997/POST_REQUEST_WITH_POSTMAN_rrycf9.png

http://res.cloudinary.com/dgq8rxb4v/image/upload/v1516182995/GET_REQUEST_WITH_POSTMAN_z0qefr.png

Thanks Jordan

Comment: You're welcome. Just curious to know if the issue was related to the missing content-type or something else?
Thanks,
Manas

Comment: I think its due to request["Content-Type"] = 'application/json' was missing in the request.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got It !

Here's the code for creating user from Quickbooks Controller

```
def create_qb_customer
    data =
    {
      "Notes": "This is from Darta",
      "GivenName": "#{params[:first_name]}",
      "FamilyName": "#{params[:last_name]}",
      "CompanyName": "#{params[:company]}",
   "PrimaryEmailAddr": {
     "Address": "#{params[:email]}"
   }
    }
  realm_id = QbToken.last.realm_id
  url = URI("https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/#{realm_id}/customer/")
  http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
  request["Content-Type"] = 'application/json'
  request["Authorization"] = "Bearer #{QbToken.last.serial}"
  request["Cache-Control"] = 'no-cache'
  request["Postman-Token"] = 'XXXXXX-cf4c-XXXXX-8d7c-XXXXXXXXX'
  request.body = data.to_json
  response = http.request(request)
  p response.read_body
  flash.notice = "Your QuickBooks customer is successfully created !"
  redirect_to list_all_project_path
  end
```